# I received an auto-reply for an email that was sent over two years ago. How did this happen?

Tags: email, auto-responder

I administer a web app that occasionally sends re-engagement and marketing emails. I recently received an auto-reply from a marketing email that was sent over two years ago, which made me concerned that the old email was somehow re-sent by my app. However, I can't find any evidence of this.

The email had been sent to a .edu email address, so I was wondering- is there some reason an auto-reply might be delayed for up to a year, or could the email's original delivery have been delayed by the mail server somehow? I am at a loss as to why this auto-reply was triggered for an email sent over two years ago.

Any insight into what might've caused this?

Answer (score 1):

The auto-reply could have been stuck in the queue of an [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_transport_agent) which was switched off. When restarted, it purged its queue (sending the awaiting message(s), including yours).